# Why does Unity become slow when switching between the Menus?

Tags: themes, appmenu

I have a big problem with Unity in terms of speed (I don't remember having this sort of problems with Gnome 2.x), my pc became slow when switching between the menus (in the same application).

Using the global menu or the normal menu for applications that haven't been ported yet. I have a Asus 1215N netbook.

I think the problem comes from the theme because this doesn't happens with Gnome3 Fallback or Gnome-Shell, but it happens with Unity-2D.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an understood problem. No, you can't fix it, unless you're a programmer.

To explain the technical details, application menus in Unity are broadcasted over [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus), and depending on the menu complexity and toolkit implementation, this can result in noticeable lag. XUL (the backend for Firefox and Thunderbird) is notoriously bad in this regard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^^ That really helped me understanding the problem. I am myself a programmer but I don't think I have the skills to solve that kind of problem :S...